# how to call a jquery function after executing and binding of elements by different jquery function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When I am calling `SaveEstimate()` (code below) the value of `$('#Offset_GrandTotal')` is coming as `0` but I expect it as `1300`.

Where I am incorrect? please guide me

```js
function calculateOffsetTaxes() {

  var OffsetTaxAmount = 500;
  var FinalCostAfterAddingMarkup = 800;

  var tempFinalGrand = (parseFloat(OffsetTaxAmount) + parseFloat(FinalCostAfterAddingMarkup)).toFixed(2);
  $('#Offset_GrandTotal').val(tempFinalGrand);
}


function GetOffsetCost() {
  $('#Offset_GrandTotal').val() == 0; //for some reasons i assign it to zero
  calculateOffsetTaxes();
}

function SaveEstimate() {

  $.ajax({

    type: "Post",
    async: true,
    url: "@Url.Content("~/MobileEstimation/CreateOffsetEstimates")",
    data: $("#PartialEstimationOffsetPrinting").serialize(),
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });

}
```

```html
<form id="PartialEstimationOffsetPrinting">
  <input type=text id="Offset_GrandTotal">
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="     GetOffsetCost()" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is the code contains inside success callback ?

Comment: Which place you can call SaveEstimate()  function?

Comment: *"I assign it to zero"* - nope, no you don't, look again.

Comment: You can call SaveEstimate() function  for after call the calculateOffsetTaxes().

Comment: @freedomm ,,sorry i am not assiging

Comment: We have no evidence that you're calling `calculateOffsetTaxes()` - so the value will have its default value (likely 0).  We also have no evidence of how you are asserting the value ("*is coming out as 0*") - is this in the MVC action? If so, include the action signature (the bit with the parameters, not the whole action).

Comment: `== 0` does nothing, perhaps you meant `$('#Offset_GrandTotal').val(0);` to assign it to zero.

Comment: I want to bind the result of calculateOffsetTaxes() but every time i am getting zero.why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bind the result of" - maybe you just need to add `return tempFinalGrand;` to the end of your calculate function?  You've not provided any code on how you're using this, so it's just guess work.

Comment: bind the result of" means id="Offset_GrandTotal" becomes 1300 and the in the saveEstimate() i could use for further saving actionresult using mvc

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
function calculateOffsetTaxes() {

var OffsetTaxAmount = 500;
var FinalCostAfterAddingMarkup = 800;

var tempFinalGrand = (parseFloat(OffsetTaxAmount) + 
parseFloat(FinalCostAfterAddingMarkup)).toFixed(2);
$('#Offset_GrandTotal').val(tempFinalGrand);
SaveEstimate($('#Offset_GrandTotal').val());
}


function GetOffsetCost() {
$('#Offset_GrandTotal').val() == 0; //for some reasons i assign it to zero
calculateOffsetTaxes();
}

function SaveEstimate(Offset_GrandTotal) {
GrandTotal = JSON.stringfy(Offset_GrandTotal)

$.ajax({
type: "Post",
async: true,
url: "@Url.Content("~/MobileEstimation/CreateOffsetEstimates
")",
data: GrandTotal,
datatype: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(data) {
//bind your data to the conrtol here
}
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:    


function calculateOffsetTaxes() {

      var OffsetTaxAmount = 500;
      var FinalCostAfterAddingMarkup = 800;

      var tempFinalGrand = (parseFloat(OffsetTaxAmount) + parseFloat(FinalCostAfterAddingMarkup)).toFixed(2);
      $('#Offset_GrandTotal').val(tempFinalGrand);
SaveEstimate(tempFinalGrand);
    }


    function GetOffsetCost() {
      $('#Offset_GrandTotal').val() == 0; //for some reasons i assign it to zero
      calculateOffsetTaxes();
    }

    function SaveEstimate(tempFinalGrand) {
    alert(tempFinalGrand);
      $.ajax({

        type: "Post",
        async: true,
        url: "@Url.Content("~/MobileEstimation/CreateOffsetEstimates
        ")",
        data: $("#PartialEstimationOffsetPrinting").serialize(),
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function(data) {

        }
      });

    }
```